# Giving Variable The Same Name As Command Crashes App

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I found a rather strange behavior in autoLISP where when you access a variable, `(setq L 1)`, that has the same name as an autoCad alias, `L` which calls the `line` command, this crashes CAD.

I can fix this by renaming the variable in lisp to something else, but it seems kind of strange that autoLISP wouldn't scope these variables since there could be a huge amount of interference between variable names and autoCad alias's/ commands.

Is there a way in autoLisp to scope these variables or is there a naming convention for them to prevent this kind of interference?

Note: The `L` command is actually an alias to the `line` command, so im wondering if the implimentation of the alias's is what's causing this.

Comment: Is AutoLISP a Lisp-1?  You can test this by, for instance `(setq kar car)` then, say `(kar '(1 2))`: if that works it almost certainly is.  If it's a Lisp-1 with dynamic scope (I believe it does have dynamic scope), then this would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: @tfb i will check. If that's the case, that makes total (unfortunate) sense.

Comment: What version of AutoCAD are you using? I cannot replicate this behaviour in AutoCAD 2018 - I can successfully assign a value to the `line` symbol as both a global and local variable, without AutoCAD crashing...

Comment: @LeeMac 2017. I think it has more to do with the fact that the variable being assigned to has the same name as an alias to a command. It's not just the `line` command, but its an alias using that name.

Comment: have you tried restarting your program? or even computer? does it still happen after that?